# SQL Syntax Error - Unsure if it is empty value or backslash

Tags: mysql

I am getting a syntax error when the following query is being run:-

```
 INSERT INTO mw_reward_point_order VALUES(9477,0,0,144,,'100/1')
```

I originally thought it was because there was an empty value between the two `,` as I can manually populate the empty value like below and it works fine:-

```
 INSERT INTO mw_reward_point_order VALUES(9477,0,0,144,1,'100/1')
```

But I am not entirely sure, as the error reads `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use **near ''100/1')'** at line 1, query was: INSERT INTO mw_reward_point_order VALUES(9477,0,0,144,,'100/1')`

Please could someone point out what exactly the syntax error is? Is it the lack of value between the two commas or in fact the backslash in the last value - possibly not being escaped?

Comment: can you show us the table design? is the last field and `int` or `varchar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to omit a column you can either apply a column list:

```
INSERT INTO mw_reward_point_order (col_1,col_2col_3,col_4,col_6)
VALUES(9477,0,0,144,'100/1')
```

or specify NULL:

```
INSERT INTO mw_reward_point_order VALUES(9477,0,0,144,NULL,'100/1')
```

Comment: We did indeed check the variable and inserted NULL if empty - that did the trick, thank you.